# GlassFish Server (open source) ColdFusion "requested resource is not available" error

Tags: coldfusion, glassfish, fusebox

We are in the process of moving a website coded in ColdFusion and Fusebox framework to a new host (from GoDaddy who is ceasing to support CF to HostMySite).

Our url structure is currently setup like /index.cfm/home.register redirecting through a cfscript to the "full" url of /index.cfm?fuseaction=home.register

We are receiving the following error message:

> HTTP Status 404 -
>
> type Status report
>
> message
>
> descriptionThe requested resource () is not available.
> GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1

I am not a CF or Windows guy, this is an old site and we are just trying to get it to run on another server to bide us some time until we can rewrite it.

Any clue as to how to what is wrong and how to get it to work? HostMySite support has been completely unresponsive thus far.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several discussion with tech support, we confirmed that "GlassFish Server" is an open source ColdFusion server, and it does not support the search engine friendly URL code we were using. We had to switch hosts to a host that used actual CF server.

Answer (score 2):

Brandon, just for the sake of correctness; Glassfish is Oracle's java server and comes in an open source flavour. http://glassfish.java.net/

Glassfish is not a ColdFusion server. 
It is possible to deploy j2ee versions of Adobe ColdFusion, Railo or OpenBD using glassfish.

JRun is the only Java server that comes with the SES rewriting built in. However, it is possible to rewrite urls using most Java servers or at the least by fronting the java server with a web server such as IIS, Apache or nginx.